# Shaving my head

Tags: hair, shaving

I'm going bald and, consequently, I'm thinking of shaving my head.  I suffer from ingrown hairs and cannot shave my face with a razor.  Any advice?

Answer (score 4):

You can use head shaver/trimmer, e.g. something like this:

[image: electric rechargeable head shaver]

[Source](https://www.ebay.com/itm/164765256410). (Just random result when searching for head shaver on Google.)

You won't get "smooth" skin but as you say you can't use razor due to ingrown hairs, so having the hair trimmed very close to the skin is probably your best option.

Comment: Agree 100%.  A beard trimmer can function as a head shaver also.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers do well discussing trimmers with adjustable heights.  But if you prefer not to have head-stubble, there are certainly options.

A majority of black men deal with ingrown hairs and/or [Pseudofolliculitis Barbae](https://www.aocd.org/page/pseudofolliculitisb) (razor bumps).  As such, there are products specifically designed for these issues.  For reasons that are often very sad, many stores do not carry these products.  As such, it's likely you have never heard of them or seen them before.

One of the popular products to deal with these issues is the Bump Fighter razor:
[image: Bump Fighter Razors]

The only big downside to the Bump Fighter razor is that it is disposable, which obviously generates environmental waste.

For this reason, rechargeable foil shavers are often popular with black men.  They lift the hair with a metal foil, and then cut it close, without cutting it so close that the hair is likely to become ingrown.

For a good list of recommendations of specific rechargeable foil shavers that may help prevent ingrown hairs, you may want to [take a look at this article](https://beyondages.com/best-mens-razor-for-black-men/).

*Please note that I am ***not*** affiliated with any of the products, companies, organizations, or websites mentioned in this answer.*

Answer (score 1):

I suffer from ingrown hairs.  I also shave my head and “have to” because I get that weird friar look if I don’t.

An electric trimmer is for sure an option, but an alternative is to shave in the shower. I trim my facial hair with electric trimmers, so I shave only my neck and head in the shower.  I do it every other day (every day causes irritation and/or ingrown hairs).

I use a Gillette Fusion razor.  Having tried others - including safety razors and several different brands - I find I get the smoothest, cleanest shave with this.

In the shower I will soften my hair with warm water and conditioner or  shampoo for a couple minutes. Then I shave by feel with shaving gel.  I haven’t found any brand to be superior to another, but I prefer gels to foams and soaps.

Additionally, I haven’t found any aftershave to help or hurt ingrown hairs, but when I want to smell nice, I use lotion or aftershave gel.

I go through about a blade a week, so this comes to about $15 on blades a month, plus whatever shaving cream costs.  I used to get ingrown hairs something awful, but now if I get any, they are very minor and on my neck.  I never get any on my head.

Answer (score 0):

My wife prefers using a beard trimmer with the plastic length guide off. This leaves a little of the color from the root.

When you shave fully down to the skin it can appear unhealthy.

Answer (score 0):

Having that 'problem', how about shaving down to 1 mm.
So you don't suffer from ingrown hairs and it looks quite nice.